# Kmeans2 returning the ordered centroids list based on how many data points they correspond to

Tags: opencv, cluster-analysis

I am using the Opencv Kmeans2() clustering function on some data set. Practically the cluster centroids start by being initialized randomly. Then clustering precedes.

How do I request all those centroids in a certain order, say first cetroid of the largest chunk of the data set, then next (in decreasing order, assuming that there's no equal set of different point locations in multidimensional space) and so on ?

Comment: It would be better if you could explain your question little more, may be provide extra details like code, result what you got and what you expect etc.

Comment: Right ... Say I have 100 samples and I specify 3 clusters randomly .... But I know beforehand that 50 samples are for one label , 30 for another, 20 for another. How do I request the centroids for the 50 samples, 30, 20 in that order ?

Comment: ( I am not sure I got your question correctly) If you know them beforehand, why do you apply kmeans? You can directly group them and find their centroids manually.

Comment: Because I dont know their location ... All I know is "a large quantity is present , another similar one is there and so on " ... Consider the following example : an image with foreground and background . ..and i know that more pixels are bg and less are fg. Runnig clustering will give two centroids . How do I request the centroids in the following order using cvkmeans2 : bg first and fg second ... Is there a hierarchy in which they are stored withi the centers matrix ?

Comment: i don't think there is an hierarchy or order. Isn't possible to count the labels and sort them according to their number? is count how many 0 and 1. If 0 is more, 0 is bg (since you know bg is more) and 1 is fg.

Comment: Ok ... thaks for the suggestion. as for your initial query and reason for downgrading my question ... please note there is no code to begin with and my question is merely on how to request some information if I were to program it using Kmeans2 function from opencv

Comment: You have a misunderstanding. I didn't downgrade your question. I am also just learning to use KMeans functionality of OpenCV and me too had this question in my mind, about hierarchy of labelling, ie how can i know which label correspond to which cluster. And I am also trying it for this foreground extraction here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111504/selecting-best-range-of-values-from-histogram-curve. Then how can i downgrade your question which is same as my problem? the reason I asked for code is, I didn't understand question first, only from comments I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you order them as you like yourself?

For most CV applications, this is not necessary, and you can do it as easily yourself, I guess. It's not as if there was an optimized k-means that returned clusters in a particular order. As k-means is initialized randomly, there is no "natural" order of the clusters. And as you already noted, there can be ties, both in cluster assignment and cluster sizes.

Comment: Ok so all I want is to return the centroid of the largest cluster ...then the next one and so on

Comment: So, try to do that. It's not that hard. But I doubt that OpenCV k-means has this as a built-in function, because that is not the common or general use case.

Answer (score 0):

I am planning to count up the labels and see to which of the centroid cluster belongs the most of the data set